# Is there a simple math solution to sample a disk area light? (Raytracing)

Tags: rendering, shadow, shapes, raytracing, light

I'm trying to implement different types of lights in my ray-tracer coded in C. I have successfully implemented spot, point, directional and *rectangular area* lights.

For *rectangular area light* I define two vectors (U and V) in space and I use them to move into the virtual (delimited) rectangle they form.
Depending on the intensity of the light I take several samples on the rectangle then I calculate the amount of the light reaching a point as though each sample were a single spot light. 
[image: rectangular light samples]

With rectangles it is very easy to find the position of the various samples, but things get complicated when I try to do the same with a *disk light*.
I found little documentation about that and most of them already use ready-made functions to do so.
The only interesting thing I found is this document (https://graphics.pixar.com/library/DiskLightSampling/paper.pdf) but I'm unable to exploit it.

Would you know how to help me achieve a similar result (of the following image) with vector operations? (ex. Having the origin, orientation, radius of the disk and the number of samples)
[image: Disk light samples]

Any advice or documentation in this regard would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question reduces to:

> How can I pick a uniformly-distributed random point on a disk?

A naive approach would be to generate random [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) and transform them to cartesian coordinates:

1. Randomly generate an angle `θ` between `0` and `2π`
2. Randomly generate a distance `d` between `0` and radius `r` of your disk
3. Transform to cartesian coordinates with `x = r cos θ` and `y = r sin θ`

This is incorrect because it causes the points to bunch up in the center; for example:

[image: Incorrect uniform disk sampling]

A correct, but inefficient, way to do this is via [rejection sampling](https://danielthompson.net/disc-rejection-sampling):

1. Uniformly generate random `x` and `y`, each over `[0, 1]`
2. If `sqrt(x^2 + y^2) < 1`, return the point
3. Goto 1

[image: disk rejection sampling]

The correct way to do this is illustrated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html):

1. Randomly generate an angle `θ` between `0` and `2π`
2. Randomly generate a distance `d` between `0` and radius `r` of your disk
3. Transform to cartesian coordinates with `x = sqrt(r) cos θ` and `y = sqrt(r) sin θ`

Comment: But how do I transform those points given an orientation and an origin for the disk?